# Help adding the Prime Number Hypothesis by C.F. Gauss to my Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, math, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Hey all!
So I'm almost done with a problem that I started working on for school that deals with the Sieve of Eratosthenes. I managed to get the program to print out all the prime numbers from 2 to the square root of 1000. However, my teacher is asking me to use the Prime Number Hypothesis (?) by C.F. Gauss. This is what he says:
C. F. Gauss hypothesized that (N) the number of primes less than or equal to N is defined
as (N) = N/loge(N) as N approaches infinity. This was called the prime number
hypothesis. In a for loop print the prime numbers, a counter indicating its ordinal
number (1, 2, 3, etc.) and the value of (N).

I tried making another for loop, and printing the prime numbers but it's just not working for me! :( ugh.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
import math
def sieves(N): 
    x = 1000*[0]        
      prime = 2
      print('2')
      i = 3
      while (i <= N):
         if i not in x:
            print(i)
            prime += 1
            j = i
            while (j <= (N / i)):
               x.append(i * j)
               j += 1
         i += 2
      print("\n")
def main():
    count = 0
    for i in range (1000):
       count = count + 1
    print(sieves(math.sqrt(1000)))

main()
```

Comment: There's no need for a space between every line :)

Comment: not quite sure, but might this hypothesis mean that you can simply exit the loop at some point (ie break or simply return)? Also you should be clear as to whether you print your numbers inside the function, or print a result as in print(sieves... 
Also I don't see the log?

Comment: @nicolas78 no it's supposed to just predict the number of primes up to whatever N is, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the line j=i. You want to start j = 1 so that you catch all multiples of i and add them to your "x" list of non-prime elements. If you start j = i you will miss some. And when you test for "i not in x" it will evaluate to true for some non-primes.

Also instead of x.append(i*j) you probably meant x[i*j] = 1 (i.e. set to 1 means i*j == not prime)
With that modification "i not in x" can be optimized to "x[i] == 0", no reason to search the entire array. This would be a lot more efficient than keeping a sparse array "x" and having to search it's elements every step in the loop.